# Explain the logic behind the execution of find function inisde for loop in Parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Below is the code:

```
function f1() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Group");
    query.equalTo("parent", arr[i]);
    var position = pos[i];
    alert("pos[i] = " + pos[i] + " position = " + position);
    query.find({
      success: function(users) {
        if (users.length === 0) {
          alert("in if");
        } else {
          alert("in else");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Basically, Group is the Parse class, arr contains the Objects of Class Parse.User and pos is array which stores integer For now contain 2 integers: 8, 15 and also arr contains two values and for i = 0 users.length != 0 and for i = 1, users.length = 0. So basically, when this function is called output i want is:

```
pos[i] = 8 position = 8
in else
pos[i] = 15 position = 15
in if
```

But actaully, i get this:

```
pos[i] = 8 position = 8
pos[i] = 15 position = 15      // I don't know why i am getting this, it is irritating me
in else
pos[i] = 15 position = 15
in if
```

I have searched on the internet and google about this issue, but can't find any better solution. So how to get the desired output?

Comment: Parse APi calls are asynchronous. Your loop will be done before data is even returned. Not exactly clear what your problem is other than that

Comment: I have editted the post... Basically what i want to do is loop through all the user and then all the groups whose parent(which is a pointer) points to this user then print to console those group object's name field so i was using find within find

Comment: Have no idea what you are trying to do. The alerts are firing in expected sequence. Don't use alerts for this sort of debugging. Use console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Never use `alert` for debugging, you will be mislead by the effects it has on when things happen. Almost always, you want to use the debugger built into your browser. On the occasions where even that messes up timings, log things via `console.log`.

But the main issue here is that the `query.find` call's work is *asynchronous*, it calls the `success` function later, after your loop is complete.

If you want to know what position and such were found, you can bind that information to your `success` callback and have it output it:

```
    var position = pos[i];
    query.find({
        // Note first arg v
        success: function(pos, users) {
            if (users.length === 0) {
                console.log("in if, pos = " + pos);  
            } else {
                console.log("in else, pos = " + pos);
            }
        }.bind(null, position) // *** Note bind
    });
```

`Function#bind` returns a new "bound" function that, when called, will call the original function with a given `this` value (not used above, hence the initial `null`), then any arguments you passed into `bind`, then the arguments passed to the bound function.

That can be a bit tricky to grasp, so here's a simpler example:

```js
function foo(a, b) {
  snippet.log("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
}
var f = foo.bind(null, 'one');
f('two'); // Shows a = one, b = two
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

If you want to do them in a strict order, you have to wait for one call to complete before starting the next:

```
function f1() {
    var i = 0;

    doOne();

    function doOne() {
        var query = new Parse.Query("Group");
        var position = pos[i];
        query.equalTo("parent", arr[i]);
        query.find({
          success: function(users) {
            if (users.length === 0) {
                alert("in if");
            } else {
                alert("in else");
            }
            if (++i < arr.length) {
                doOne();
            }
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This was working, butdoes this works in random fashion means some times first 15 in printed on the console and then 8 and sometime opposite of this?

Comment: @jain: It's probably not *random*, but yes, some queries may finish sooner than ones started before them. If you don't want that, don't start subsequent queries until you've had the success callback from the previous one.

Comment: @jain: I've added to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Promise.when() as follows:

```
    var queries = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   
        var query = new Parse.Query("Group");
        query.equalTo("parent", arr[i]);
        var position = pos[i];
        alert("pos[i] = " + pos[i] + " position = " + position);
        queries.push(query.find());
    }
    Parse.Promise.when(queries).then(function() {
        var users = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        // users will contain the results of each query in corresponding positions
    });
```

The idea is that find() returns a promise to complete the asynch find, and Promise.when() returns a promise that's fulfilled when all of the promises passed to it are complete.

Comment: I am geting TypeError: a is undefined... :( on queries.push(query.find()); Don't know why?